# XMLHttpRequest и многопоточная загрузка файлов

Tags: javascript, ajax, fileupload, xmlhttprequest

Здравствуйте.

На странице имеем

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

К нему привязано следующее событие на 'onChange':

```
for (i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {     
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("afile", this.files[i]);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'image_upload.php', true);

    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
            console.log(percentComplete + '% uploaded');
        }
    };
    xhr.send(fd);

 }
```

Если выбрать сразу несколько файлов, то в консоль сыпятся счетчики с разных потоков. Как понять статус загрузки конкретного файла?

Вопрос решил следующим способом:

```
for (i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {     
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("afile", this.files[i]);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'image_upload.php', true);

    let fileName = 'file' + i;

    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
            console.log(fileName+': 'percentComplete + '% uploaded');
        }
    };
    xhr.send(fd);

 }
```

Теперь можно понять прогресс загрузки каждого из файлов! 
Всем спасибо, вопрос закрыт.

Comment: может быть не конкретного сайта, а конкретного файла?

Comment: Раз помог вопрос по ссылке, можно согласиться с тем что это дубликат и вопрос пометится закрытым

Comment: Да, это решение появилось после прочтения вопроса по ссылке. Там эта тема раскрыта максимально подробно. Только вот у меня кнопки нет, чтобы согласиться и закрыть мой вопрос.